# Microsoft Windows Azure Web Host has stopped working

Tags: asp.net, telerik, azure

I am developing a web application with Azure Cloude Service and using ASP.NET 3.5, Telerik ASP.NET Ajax control and MSSQL-SERVER 2008 R2. I fetching problem while debugging. my problem is bellow :

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: WaWebHost.exe
  Application Version:  6.0.6002.18005
  Application Timestamp:    4b664006
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7600.16385
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4a5bdaae
  Exception Code:   e0434f4d
  Exception Offset: 00009617
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 5c29
  Additional Information 2: 5c295a1b2eb24a0ea3f29406dc25673d
  Additional Information 3: 9010
  Additional Information 4: 90104f30ea225c918a91dfa52350dfc6

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

What is the problem !!!

Comment: Need some detail.  Do you have a stack trace?  Does this work on the Development Fabric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unhandled exception, most likely in some .Net code.  If you have the full thread stack, we could probably tell you more.